# How to "Clear All" Windows 10 Action Center notifications with keyboard

Tags: windows, windows-10

In Windows 10 desktop, is there way to "Clear All" of the Action Center notifications with the keyboard?

I know <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> will open the Action Center. But I haven't found a shortcut to dismiss the notifications.

Comment: Can you not navigate around with arrow keys and `Enter` to select desired option(s) after using `Win` `A`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try:

<kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (to open Action Center)

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (to set focus on "clear all")

<kbd>Space</kbd>

The above keystrokes can be automated using NirCmd or AHK easily.

Comment: I may have spoke too soon. It works, but it's not ideal. Apparently shift+tab doesn't work, so you have to Tab about 7 times to get to "Clear All" :(

Comment: A keyboard sequence this is. A keyboard shortcut? Seems like a bit of a longcut to me. Sadly, this may be the best that Redmond is offering us. :-(

Comment: The first Shift+Tab only focuses the settings tiles within the Action Center for me; a second press focuses the Clear All button.

Comment: This answer is not completely accurate. While you can automate those key combinations with AHK, if you happen to press it when there's no notifications it'll trigger random actions from your Action Center icons, or open the Action Center settings window.

Answer (score 1):

For AutoHotKey users, this little script works for me (Win10 Pro 20H2/19042):

```
^F12::
    Send, {LWIN DOWN}a{LWIN UP}{SHIFT DOWN}{TAB}{TAB}{SHIFT UP}{SPACE}{ESC}
    return
```

This makes the hotkey Ctrl+F12 clear all notifications (Based on w32sh's answer). You can change the hotkey by changing the `^F12` to anything you like, eg. `#F6` for the Windows key+F6 or `^m` for Ctrl+m.

Copy into a file called `ClearNotifications.ahk` and run, if you have AutoHotKey installed.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when doing that manually the solution of <kbd>WinKey</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd>, always works... but it doesn't when doing it from AutoIt.

This little script for AutoIt will either:

a) If there are any notifications, it will clear them all

b) If there aren't, it will expand or contract the buttons (Tablet, config, etc...) from below.

```
    Send("#a")
    Sleep(100)
    Send("{ENTER}")
    Send("{ESC}")
```

Comment: Odd. I couldn't get Shift+Tab to work manually. I'm on Win 10 Home 64 bit.

Comment: @Drew S Seems an unrelated issue, as shift added to a navigation key generally reverses the action.  This is standard across windows, chrome, Linux desktops, etc.  If the key combination isn't working I would look towards my keyboard or something such as filter keys in the OS affecting the input.

Answer (score 0):

In AHK `Win+Alt+N` Clear all notifications. Tested on Windows 11.

```
#!N::
Send #n
Send +{Tab}
Send +{Tab} 
Send {Space} 
Send {Esc}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

- `WinKey` + `A` to open Action Center
- `WinKey` + `A` again to close it

At this point notifications are cleared out

Comment: NO, it's not be cleared, it still there, just highlight of notification icon was cleared from having notifications -> blank state